# How to get all key-value pairs of a PDF form fields using javascript in Acrobat?

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I have searched and found out code snippet for getting a value for particular field in a PDF using javascript in Acrobat.

But I need to get all fields as key-value pair in javascript. I tried some of the code but it won't work for me.

```
if(this.hostContainer) {    
        var names = new Array();    
        names[0] = this.getField("personal.name").value.toString(); 
        names[1] = this.getField("personal.loginname").value.toString();    
        try{    
            this.hostContainer.postMessage(names);  
        }   
        catch(e){   
            app.alert(e.message);   
        }   
}
```

PDF file looks like below,

> Name : x (editable)
>
> Age : 36 (editable)
>
> Sex : male (editable)

But the form fields in PDF may vary.

Comment: Please elaborate on `it won't work for me`.

Comment: Unable to get all fields key value pairs.I didn't  see any java script methods to get all key value pairs

Comment: If you have additional information, please add it to your question. It will make it clearer and increase the likelihood of people answering it.

Comment: Unable to get key value pair in java script. The sample pdf looks like above.but the pdf may vary (both key and value). How can i get this?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way is as follows; you run this code from the Console:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < this.numFields ; i++) {
var fn = this.getNthFieldName(i) ;
if (fn.type != "button") {
console.println("Name: " + fn + "   Value: " + this.getField(fn).valueAsString) 
}
}
```

And that should do it.

If you want to create a report, you could use the Report object, or you could create a Data Object (in either case, you would write to the target, and not to the console).

Comment: Already i have gone through the above code snippet. But my problem is "How can i get the pdf document object " in java script function.

Comment: If it is the document itself, you would use "this"; if it is another document, you get its doc object with app.openDoc() ; you might have to set the disclosed flag of the other document to true, in order to have access to it.